# couchbase security, can I restrict the moxi port 11211 to local host

Tags: security, memcached, couchbase

I feel like I must be really thick here but I'm struggling with couchbase configuration.

I am looking to replace memcached with couchbase and am wanting to secure things more to my liking, on the server their are a number of applications that are set up to use memcached so it needs to be as drop in as possible without changing the applications configuration.

What I have done is installed couchbase on each of the webservers like I did with memcached and so far with my config everything is working.

The problem I have is port 11211 is open to the world a large and this terrifies me, either I'm thick or I'm not looking in the right place but I want to restrict port 11211 to only be listening on localhost 127.0.0.1.

Now couchbase seems to have reams and reams of documentation but I cannot find how to do this and am starting to feel like you need to be a couchbase expert to make simple changes.

I'm aware that the security of couchbase is to use password protected buckets with SASL auth but for me this isn't an option.

While I'm on the subject and if I can change the listening interface, are their any other ports with couchbase that don't need to be open to the world and can be restricted to local host.

Many many thanks in advance for any help, I'm at my wits end.

Comment: This is a system level change that you need to make and isn't something that is Couchbase specific. What you will want to do is restrict access to port 11211 through your firewall settings. How you do this depends on your os and I don't think you mentioned that in the question. If you let me know your os I will try to circle back and help you find the right commands.

Comment: Hi mikewid, I'm using ubuntu 12.04 I can set the firewall rules if that's the solution do you know if any other external ports on couchbase and be restricted without ill effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's back up a bit. Unlike memcached, Couchbase is really meant to be installed as a separate tier in your infrastructure and as a cluster even if you are just using it as a high availability cache. A better architecture would be to have Couchbase installed on its own properly sized nodes (in a cluster using Couchbase buckets) and then install Moxi (Couchbase's memcached proxy) on each web server that will talk to the Couchbase cluster on your app's behalf. This architecture will give you the functionality you need, but then give you the high availability, replication, failover, etc that Couchbase is known for.

In the long run, I would recommend that you transition your code to using Couchbase's client SDKs to access the cluster as that will give you the most benefits, performance, resilience, etc. for your caching needs. Moxi is meant more as an interim step, not a final destination.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer as in the long term it's correct the setup I have is way short of ideal, in the short term to keep things going and so I can sleep at night I have blocked the port from external access without ill effect.